# Parsing HTML to get elements between two set elements

Tags: perl, css-selectors, html-parsing

I am trying to parse a page like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne_Rooney) and I simply want to get the paragraphs after the header, the introduction I guess.

I want all the content (inclduing the paragraph tags) between `<table class="infobox vcard">` and `<table id="toc">`. Using simple CSS selectors to get even the first paragraph:

`div#bodyContent div#mw-content-text.mw-content-ltr p`

does not always work because sometimes something in the infobox table has a paragraph. Also, the amount of introductory paragraphs will vary. If someone has a better approach than what I'm going for here, I will also be receptive to that.

--

Additional code requested, shortened as much as possible:

```
require HTTP::Request;
require LWP::UserAgent;

use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::Query 'Query';

my $pageurl = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne_Rooney";
my $wikiurl = URI->new($pageurl);
my $wikirequest = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $wikiurl);
my $wikiua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $wikiresponse = $wikiua->request($wikirequest);
my $pagetoparse = $wikiresponse->content;

my $q2 = Query(text => $pagetoparse);
my @wikiintro = $q2->query('div#bodyContent div#mw-content-text.mw-content-ltr p')->get_elements();
my $pageintro;
if(@wikiintro) {
    if(index($wikiintro[0]->as_text(), "Appearances (Goals)") != -1){
        $pageintro = $wikiintro[1]->as_text();
    } else {
        $pageintro = $wikiintro[0]->as_text();
    }
} else {
    $pageintro = "unavailable";
}
```

Comment: I said what I have tried: "Using simple CSS selectors to get even the first paragraph:" is what I tried to get the intro paragraph, and I said why that did not work and why even if it did I want the other paragraphs. As far as trying to figure out how to approach the in between div thing goes, I have Googled multiple different queries and I am unable to come up with anything.

Comment: Could you show us some code, please? Which modules did you use? If you are using the [Mojolicious Useragend](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent) there might be some tricks to get the correct output.

Comment: I will provide the code of what I am doing now, but I should repeat: What I am doing only gets the first paragraph. I have found out a way to avoid the problem where it sometimes picks up a paragraph in the table with class "infobox" which you can see in the code. However, I still don't think this is the right approach as I don't think I can get the other paragraphs and know when to stop (when the table id "toc") starts.

Comment: In other words, it is almost completely irrelevant to what I am trying to do, it was more of a placeholder effort until I figured out how to even approach getting the in-between elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using the non-standard module `HTML::TreeBuilder`.

Content of `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my (@p);

## Read the web page.
my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url( shift ) or die qq|ERROR: Malformed URL\n|;

## Get the table tag with id = 'toc'.
my $table_toc = $root->look_down(
    id => 'toc'
);

## Get inmediate previous siblings <p> tags.
for my $node ( reverse $table_toc->left ) { 
    if ( $node->tag eq 'p' ) { 
        unshift @p, $node;
    }   
    else {
        last;
    }   
}

## Print the content without the HTML tags.
for my $p ( @p ) { 
    printf qq|%s\n|, $p->as_text;
}
```

Run it providing the url as unique argument:

```
perl-5.14.2 script.pl http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne_Rooney
```

With following output (I hope it to be near of what you expect):

```
Wayne Mark Rooney (born 24 October 1985) is an English footballer who plays as a forward for Premier League club Manchester United and the England national team.
Rooney made his senior international debut in 2003 becoming the youngest player to represent England, until he got beaten by Theo Walcott. He is England's youngest ever goalscorer.[4] He played at UEFA Euro 2004 and scored four goals, briefly becoming the competition's youngest goalscorer. Rooney featured at the 2006 and 2010 World Cups and is widely regarded as his country's best player.[5][6][7][8][9][10] He has won the England Player of the Year award twice, in 2008 and 2009. As of October 2012, he has won 78 international caps and scored 32 goals, making him England's fifth highest goalscorer in history.[11] Along with David Beckham, Rooney is the most red carded player for England, having been sent off twice.[12]
Wide character in printf at script.pl line 25.
Aged nine, Rooney joined the youth team of Everton, for whom he made his professional debut in 2002. He spent two seasons at the Merseyside club, before moving to Manchester United for £25.6 million in the 2004 summer transfer window. The same year, Rooney acquired the nickname "Wazza".[13] Since then, with Rooney in the team, United have won the Premier League four times, the 2007–08 UEFA Champions League and two League Cups. He also holds two runner-up medals from the Champions League and has twice finished second in the Premier League. In April 2012, Rooney scored his 180th goal, making him United's fourth-highest goal-scorer of all time.[14]
Wide character in printf at script.pl line 25.
In 2009–10, Rooney was awarded the PFA Players' Player of the Year and the FWA Footballer of the Year. He has won the Premier League Player of the Month award five times, a record he shares with Steven Gerrard. He came fifth in the vote for the 2011 FIFA Ballon d'Or and was named in the FIFPro World 11 for 2011. Rooney has won the 'Goal of the Season' award by the BBC's Match of the Day poll on three occasions, with his bicycle kick against rivals Manchester City winning the 'Premier League Goal of the 20 Seasons' award.[15] Rooney is the third highest-paid footballer in the world after Lionel Messi and Cristiano Ronaldo, with an annual income of €20.7m (£18m) including sponsorship deals.[16]
```

---

**EDIT**: To get as result also tags use `printf qq|%s\n|, $p->as_HTML;` instead of `$p->as_text`.

Comment: I was trying to incorporate this into my existing script and was having some errors. Anyway, I just made this its own script entirely and tried to run it. I keep getting `Can't locate object method "new_from_url" via package "HTML::TreeBuilder"` Also: I do have LWP::UserAgent

Comment: Nevermind, I am using `new_from_content()` with the page content I am getting using with the code in the original post. As soon as I get this working in my intended application I will select the answer.

Comment: @MarkLyons: The `new_from_url` constructor is available in more recent release of the `HTML::TreeBuilder`. You should consider updating your module library.

Answer (score 4):

[`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) is probably the best tool for this. The trick is learning and choosing between the many methods it provides for navigating the HTML tree.

This program seems to do what you need. It calls `look_down` to find the table with the given class that is immediately before the output you require. From here a call to `right` returns all elements *after* this table at the same level in the HTML hierarchy. The loop simply prints each of these elements until it encounters an element with a tag other than `p`.

I have written this using `LWP::UserAgent`, but clearly the code would be much more concise if you updated your copy of `HTML::TreeBuilder` so that you could use the `new_from_url` constructor.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my $url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne_Rooney';
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $resp = $ua->get($url);
die $resp->status_line unless $resp->is_success;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($resp->decoded_content);

my $start = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'table', class => 'infobox vcard');

for ($start->right) {
  last if $_->tag ne 'p';
  print $_->as_trimmed_text. "\n\n";
}
```

**output**

```
Wayne Mark Rooney (born 24 October 1985) is an English footballer who plays as a forward for Premier League club Manchester United and the England national team.

Rooney made his senior international debut in 2003 becoming the youngest player to represent England, until he got beaten by Theo Walcott. He is England's youngest ever goalscorer.[4] He played at UEFA Euro 2004 and scored four goals, briefly becoming the competition's youngest goalscorer. Rooney featured at the 2006 and 2010 World Cups and is widely regarded as his country's best player.[5][6][7][8][9][10] He has won the England Player of the Year award twice, in 2008 and 2009. As of October 2012, he has won 78 international caps and scored 32 goals, making him England's fifth highest goalscorer in history.[11] Along with David Beckham, Rooney is the most red carded player for England, having been sent off twice.[12]

Aged nine, Rooney joined the youth team of Everton, for whom he made his professional debut in 2002. He spent two seasons at the Merseyside club, before moving to Manchester United for £25.6 million in the 2004 summer transfer window. The same year, Rooney acquired the nickname "Wazza".[13] Since then, with Rooney in the team, United have won the Premier League four times, the 2007–08 UEFA Champions League and two League Cups. He also holds two runner-up medals from the Champions League and has twice finished second in the Premier League. In April 2012, Rooney scored his 180th goal, making him United's fourth-highest goal-scorer of all time.[14]

In 2009–10, Rooney was awarded the PFA Players' Player of the Year and the FWA Footballer of the Year. He has won the Premier League Player of the Month award five times, a record he shares with Steven Gerrard. He came fifth in the vote for the 2011 FIFA Ballon d'Or and was named in the FIFPro World 11 for 2011. Rooney has won the 'Goal of the Season' award by the BBC's Match of the Day poll on three occasions, with his bicycle kick against rivals Manchester City winning the 'Premier League Goal of the 20 Seasons' award.[15] Rooney is the third highest-paid footballer in the world after Lionel Messi and Cristiano Ronaldo, with an annual income of €20.7m (£18m) including sponsorship deals.[16]
```